# Bug ao tentar usar o PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo a usar o SimplePythonGUI, porém estou me deparando com um bug. O problema é o seguinte: ao chegar no `if` lá em baixo, mesmo que o número `random` e o escolhido pelo usuário sejam iguais, o programa não dá o `print` de que o usuário ganhou e sempre vai para o `else`.

```
import PySimpleGUI as pg
from random import randint
class telapython:
    def __init__(self):
        #layout
        layout = [
            [pg.Text('Digite um número') , pg.Input(key= 'Pergunta')],
            [pg.Button('Verificar número')],

        ]

        #janela

        janela = pg.Window('Adivinhe o número').layout(layout)

        #extração de dados
        self.button , self.values = janela.Read()

    def iniciar(self):
        random = randint(0, 1)
        pergunta = self.values['Pergunta']
        print(random , pergunta)
        if random == pergunta:
            print('Você venceu')
        else:
            print('Você errou')

tela = telapython()
tela.iniciar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sou avançado na biblioteca TKInter, uma biblioteca similar a pysimpleGUI.
Quando rodo seu codigo só essa parte dá super certo... Parabéns!

```
    def iniciar(self):
    random = randint(0, 1)
    pergunta = self.values['Pergunta']
    print(random , pergunta)
    if random == pergunta:
        print('Você venceu')
    else:
        print('Você errou')
```

Parece que `pergunta = self.values['Pergunta']` não está pegando o valor que você põe, no TkInter uso o `.get()`, então por isso que vai direto pro else, mas no pysimpleGUI (uma pesquisa que encontrei) se usa o `.read()`.
Tente usar algo parecido com:

```
pergunta = self.values['Pergunta'].read()
pergunta = self.values.read(['Pergunta'])
pergunta.read() = self.values['Pergunta']
```

Espero que tenha ajudado,

Answer (score -1):

Utilize a conversão para `int` antes de verificar a igualdade:

```
if random == int(pergunta):
```

Answer (score -1):

Por padrão quando você recebe o Input do PySimpleGUI ele vem com 'str' você tem que transformar em 'int' da seguinte maneira.

```py
_pergunta_ = self.values['Pergunta']
_pergunta_ = int(_pergunta_)
```